# AS3 not recognising MovieClips - 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MP_00

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

So Im new to AS3, trying to make a simple videogame for smartphones.
And it was all going smooth until I hit this problem.
I was using and manipulating objects from timeline without a problem and than all the sudden whatever I try I get the 1046.

Here is some code that gets an error:

```
mp = new MP_00();
```

And at the top I have this:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
var mp:Movieclip;
```

And at the end this:

```
function mapMove(){
mp.y = mp.y - playerSpeed;
}
```

Im searching for a solution all the time, but nobody seems to have the same problem.
I do have AS linkage set to MP_00 and witch ever object I try to put in, it dosent work.
While objects put in on the same way before, they work.

For example I have this

```
var player:MovieClip;

player = new Player();
```

with AS Linkage set to Player, and that works.

This is all done in Flash Professional cs6

EDIT 1
full code
Keep in mind that a lot of stuff is placeholder or just not finished code.

On this code Im getting the error twice for the same object

```
Scene 1 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:
MP_00. 
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 165 1046: Type was not
found or was not a compile-time constant: MP_00.
```

Thats the errors.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.engine.SpaceJustifier;
import flashx.textLayout.operations.MoveChildrenOperation;

/*----------------------------Main VARs-----------------------------*/
var STATE_START:String="STATE_START";
var STATE_START_PLAYER:String="STATE_START_PLAYER";
var STATE_PLAY:String="STATE_PLAY";
var STATE_END:String="STATE_END";
var gameState:String;

var player:MovieClip;
var playerSpeed:Number;
var map:Array;
var bullets:Array;
//holds civil vehicles
var civil:Array; 
//holds enemy vehicles
var enemy:Array; 
var explosions:Array;

var BBullet:MovieClip;

//maps
var mp:MovieClip;
/*
var MP_01:MovieClip;
var MP_02:MovieClip;
var MP_03:MovieClip; 
*/

//sets the bullet type and properties
var BType = "BBasic";
var BProp:Array;

//bullet preperties by type

var BBasic:Array = new Array(1, 1, 100, 50, 0, new BBasicA());

/**
ARRAY SETTING
0 = bullet position (middle , back, sides etc...)
    1-middle front
    2-left side front
    3-right side front
    4-left and right side middle
    5-back
    7-left and right side wheels

1 = bullet direction
    1-forward
    2-back
    3-sides

2 = fire speed (in millisecounds so 1000 = 1sec)

3 = speed of movement

4 = damage 10-100

5 = name of the firing animation in library

6 = name of launch animation in library

7 = name of impact animation in library 
**/

var level:Number;

//BCivil speed and randomness
var BCSpeed:Number = 3;
var BCRand:Number = 120;

/*------------------------------Setup-------------------------------*/


introScreen.visible = false;
loadingScreen.visible = false;
gameScreen.visible = false;
endScreen.visible = false;

//map visibility
//MpRSimple.visible = false;

/*---------------------------Intro screen--------------------------*/


/*-----------------------------mainScreen---------------------------*/

mainScreen.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAway);
function clickAway(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gameStart();
    }

function gameStart():void
{
    //Move main screen from stage
    mainScreen.visible = false;

    //Begin loading the game
    loadingScreen.visible = true;
    gameState = STATE_START;
    trace (gameState);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
    }

/*----------------------------gameLoop-----------------------------*/

function gameLoop(e:Event):void
{
    switch(gameState)
    {
        case STATE_START:
            startGame();
            break;

        case STATE_START_PLAYER:
            startPlayer();
            break;

        case STATE_PLAY:
            playGame();
            break;

        case STATE_END:
            endGame();
            break;

        }
    }
/*-_________________________-Game STATES-_________________________-*/

/*---------------------------STATE_START---------------------------*/

function startGame():void
{

    level = 1; //setting level for enemies

    //Graphics
        //player icon
    player = new Player(); 
        //add bullet holder
    bullets = new Array();
        //basicCivil icon
    civil = new Array(); 
        //basicEnemy icon
    enemy = new Array(); 
        //holds explosions
    explosions = new Array(); 

    //map
    //mp = new MP_00();
    //var mp:MP_00 = new MP_00();

    //Load map parts

    //End startGame
    gameState = STATE_START_PLAYER;
    trace(gameState);
    }

/*------------------------STATE_START_PLAYER-----------------------*/

function startPlayer():void
{
    //start the player

    //set possition of player
    player.y = stage.stageHeight - player.height;
    addChild(player);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);

    //changing screens
    gameScreen.visible = true;

    //start game
    gameState = STATE_PLAY;
    trace(gameState);

    }

//player controll
function movePlayer(e:Event):void 
{

    //gameScreen.visible = true;

    //mouse\touch recognition
    player.x = stage.mouseX;
    player.y = stage.mouseY;

    //player does not move out of the stage
    if (player.x < 0)
    {
        player.x = 0;
    }
    else if (player.x > (stage.stageWidth - player.width))
    {
        player.x = stage.stageWidth + player.width;
    }

    }

//setting bullet type
if (BType == "BBasic")
{
        BProp = BBasic;
    /*case BMissile;
        BProp = BMissile;
        break; */
    }
//creating bullets


//gameScreen.fire_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireHandler());


/*
function fireHandler():void
{
    var bulletTimer:Timer = new Timer (500);
    bulletTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    bulletTimer.start();
    trace("nja");
    }

function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    //need and if statement to determine the bullet speed and travel depended on type of bullet
    var tempBullet:MovieClip = /*BProp[5] new BBasicA();
    //shoots bullets in the middle
    tempBullet.x = player.x +(player.width/2); 
    tempBullet.y = player.y;
    //shooting speed
    tempBullet.speed = 10; 
    bullets.push(tempBullet);
    addChild(tempBullet);
    //bullets movement forward
    for(var i=bullets.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempBullet = bullets[i];
        tempBullet.y -= tempBullet.speed;
        }
    }
*/

/*----------------------------STATE_PLAY---------------------------*/

function playGame():void
{
    //gameplay
    //speedUp();
    mapMove();
    //fire();
    makeBCivil();
    makeBEnemy();
    moveBCivil();
    moveBEnemy();
    vhDrops();
    testCollision();
    testForEnd();
    removeExEplosions();
    }


function mapMove(){
    mp.y = mp.y - playerSpeed;
    }

/*
function speedUp():void
{
    var f:Number;
    for (f<10; f++;)
    {
        var playerSpeed = playerSpeed + 1;
        f = 0;
        //mapMove();
        MpRSimple = new MP_RS();
        MpRSimple.y = MpRSimple.y - playerSpeed;
        trace ("speed reset");
        }
    trace (f);
    }
*/

function makeBCivil():void
{
    //random chance
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*BCRand);
    if (chance <= 1 + level) 
    {
        var tempBCivil:MovieClip;
        //generate enemies
        tempBCivil = new BCivil();
        tempBCivil.speed = BCSpeed;
        tempBCivil.x = Math.round(Math.random()*800);

        addChild(tempBCivil);
        civil.push(tempBCivil);
        }
    }

function moveBCivil():void
{
    //move enemies
    var tempBCivil:MovieClip;
    for(var i:int = civil.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempBCivil = civil[i];
        tempBCivil.y += tempBCivil.speed
        }

    //testion colision with the player and screen out
    if (tempBCivil.y > stage.stageHeight /* || tempBCivil.hitTestObject(player) */)
    {
        trace("ds hit");
        //makeExplosion (player.x, player.y);
        removeCivil(i);
        //gameState = STATE_END;
        }
    }

//Test bullet colision
function testCollision():void
{
    var tempBCivil:MovieClip;
    var tempBEnemy:MovieClip;
    var tempBullet:MovieClip;

    //civil/bullet colision
    civils:for(var i:int=civil.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempBCivil = civil[i];
        for (var j:int=bullets.length-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            tempBullet = bullets[j];
            if (tempBCivil.hitTestObject(tempBullet))
            {
                trace("laser hit the civil");
                makeExplosion (tempBCivil.x, tempBCivil.y);
                removeCivil(i);
                removeBullet(j);
                break civils;
                }
            }
        }

    //enemy/bullet colision
    enemy:for(var k:int=enemy.length-1; k>=0; k--)
    {
        tempBEnemy = enemy[k];
        for (var l:int=bullets.length-1; l>=0; l--)
        {
            tempBullet = bullets[l];
            if (tempBEnemy.hitTestObject(tempBullet))
            {
                trace("bullet hit the Enemy");
                makeExplosion (tempBEnemy.x, tempBEnemy.y);
                removeEnemy(k);
                removeBullet(l);
                break enemy;
                }
            }
        }
    }

function makeExplosion(ex:Number, ey:Number):void
{
    var tempExplosion:MovieClip;
    tempExplosion = new boom();
    tempExplosion.x = ex;
    tempExplosion.y = ey;
    addChild(tempExplosion)
    explosions.push(tempExplosion);
    }

function makeBEnemy():void
{
    //random chance
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*BCRand);
    if (chance <= 1 + level) 
    {
        var tempBEnemy:MovieClip;
        //generate enemies
        tempBEnemy = new BEnemy();
        tempBEnemy.speed = BCSpeed;
        tempBEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random()*800);

        addChild(tempBEnemy);
        enemy.push(tempBEnemy);
        }

    }

function moveBEnemy():void
{
    //move enemies
    var tempBEnemy:MovieClip;
    for(var i:int = enemy.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempBEnemy = enemy[i];
        tempBEnemy.y += tempBEnemy.speed
        }

    //testion colision with the player and screen out
    if (tempBEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight /* || tempBCivil.hitTestObject(player) */)
    {
        trace("enemy");
        //makeExplosion (player.x, player.y);
        removeEnemy(i);
        //gameState = STATE_END;
        }
    }

function vhDrops():void
{}

function testForEnd():void
{
    //check damage


    //end game
    //gameState = STATE_END;
    trace(gameState);
    }

/*--------------------REMOVING BS FROM STAGE-----------------------*/
//removing civils
function removeCivil(idx:int):void 
{
    if(idx >= 0)
    {
        removeChild(civil[idx]);
        civil.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }

//removing enemies
function removeEnemy(idx:int):void 
{
    if(idx >= 0)
    {
        removeChild(enemy[idx]);
        enemy.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }

//removing civils
function removeBullet(idx:int):void 
{
    if(idx >= 0)
    {
        removeChild(bullets[idx]);
        bullets.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }

//removing expired explosions
function removeExEplosions():void 
{
    var tempExplosion:MovieClip;
    for(var i=explosions.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempExplosion = explosions[i];
        if (tempExplosion.currentFrame >= tempExplosion.totalFrames)
        {
            removeExplosion(i);
            }
        }
    }

//removing civils
function removeExplosion(idx:int):void 
{
    if(idx >= 0)
    {
        removeChild(explosions[idx]);
        explosions.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }



/*--------------------------STATE_END------------------------------*/

function endGame():void
{

    }


/*gameScreen*/

/*endScreen*/
```

And Im sure theres some other bad code here but that doesent matter now.

Export for AS and AS Linkage is set:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvMAt.png

EDIT: removed the 2nd var declaration, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you give more code and explanations, but here what I found about 1046 : 
"One reason you will get this error is if you have an object on the stage with the same name as an object in your library."

Look at : http://curtismorley.com/2007/06/20/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-1046/

Did you search any explanation on the Web for code 1046 ?  Have you checked this one ?

I see that you have two `var mp` declaration.  Try to remove the first one, `var mp:MovieClip;`.  If it doesn't work, check your Flash Library carefully, be sure that `MP_00` is a name available.  If it's a MovieClip, check that it is exported for ActionScript. If it's an instance name, check that it's not used twice.

EDIT.

My suggestion is :

1- Change all references of `mp` to `mp1`.  Maybe there is a conflict with an instance  "...an object on the stage with the same name as an object in your library."

2- `var mp1:MP_00;` instead of `var mp:MovieClip;` in the declaration section.

3- Put the `mp1 = new MP_00();` back in the startGame() function

4- Be sure that your new `mp1` variable is everywhere you need and you have no more ref. to `mp` variable.

If... it's still doesn't work.  I suggest : Change the name of your MovieClip linkage, like `TestA`, or whatever.  Yes I know, a doubt on everything, but there is no magic, testing everything will show the problem for sure.

EDIT.

For `mapMove()` function...

First : be sure the `speedUp()` function is available, not in comments, and call it in your `playGame()` function.  Your `playerSpeed` variable must have a value, so  change : `var playerSpeed = playerSpeed + 1;` for `playerSpeed = playerSpeed + 1;`. Do not use `var` declaration twice for the same variable. (See `var playerSpeed:Number;` in header file.)

Beside... you have to know if the `MP_00` clip on stage is YOUR `mp1` clip. (I assumed you published all the code you have.)

Case A : `MP_00` is on stage when you start your Clip.

If you actually see your `MP_00` on screen, that mean you don't have to do `mp1 = new MP_00();` and `addchild(mp1);`.  It's already done for you (dragging a clip from library and giving a name instance, is the same as doing `new` and `addchild`).

Find the instance name (or give one). You should get your instance name and move your object (here the instance name is `mp1`):

```
mp1.y = mp1.y - playerSpeed;
```

Case B : `MP_00` is NOT on stage when you start your Clip.

Do :
1- your declaration : `var mp1:MP_00;`
2- allocation memory : `mp1 = new MP_00();`
3- add to the display list : `addchild(mp1);`
4- "Shake it bb" : `mp1.y = mp1.y - playerSpeed;` or `mp1.y -= playerSpeed;`

I don't know what is your knowledge level exactly, so I tried to put everything.  Sorry if it's too much.

Comment: I didnt see that before, but it doesent work, Im posting the full code

Comment: You don't have any import MP_00; If you use something, be sure that it's available for the compiler. I suggest that you look in your Flash library, and verify that your MP_00 is exported for ActionScript.  Have you checked that ?

Comment: You have two 'var mp' declaration. Remove the first one.

Comment: As I said, I have export for AS and AS Linkage set, Ill drop a picture up if you dont belive me. If I remove the first declaration I get all the previous errors plus 2 new ones saying that mp is undefined property. And if I remove the secound one I still get the MP_00 error

Comment: I believe you. I forgot that you mentioned it; I was focusing on code. See last EDIT in my answer.

Comment: The last thing you said (changing the linkage) + the 3. thing in EDIT ended up working, Thanks! Also just a little tip, in the code above where I have the mapMove function, how could I make that work? now its just standing and I need it to move with the playerSpeed number. Thanks again!

Comment: See last EDIT.  Hope that everything work fine. Good work to you.